# Cross-reference in LibreOffice Writer to a figure

Tags: libreoffice, bug-reporting

In order to insert a cross-reference for a figure, I used to do following:

- Insert cross-reference
- open the tab cross-reference
- select figure as Type
- choose the appropriate caption
- select Category and number

This used to give the following in my document:
Figure and the number of the figure. Since version 6.0.3, also in version 6.1.0, I only obtain the number, the word Figure is omitted.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?
If yes, please show me where to find some help to file the bug.

PS.: This behavior cannot be reproduced in Writer 6.0 under Windows, so to me it seems like an Ubuntu bug.